# Dynamic Message using Barcode4J in Apache FOP XSL Document

Tags: xslt, barcode, xsl-fo, apache-fop, barcode4j

I'm having trouble generating a dynamic message using Barcode4J ean-13 in an Apache FOP xsl document. I did get the barcode to generate using a hard coded message. However, I would like to pass the barcode number to the xsl document as a parameter. How do I go about doing that?

Also, I have referred to the barcode4J [site](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.1/fop-ext.html) for help page with no luck. I have tried using the technique described [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/barcode4j/mailman/message/21965884/) but had no luck.

This is how my xsl document looks like

```
<fo:block-container left="1000" top="1000"
            z-index="1" position="relative">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                    <bc:barcode xmlns:bc="http://barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns"
                        message="123456789789">
                        <bc:ean-13 />
                    </bc:barcode>
                </fo:instream-foreign-object>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which XSLT version you are using.

If you want to pass a parameter to your XSLT, you need to declare the parameter as a child element of your `xsl:stylesheet`, e.g.:

```
<xsl:param name="barcode" />
```

For XSLT 1.0, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#top-level-variables.  You could declare more about it if you are using XSLT 2.0.

How to pass the parameter value will depend on which XSLT processor you are using, but you can expect that to be covered in the XSLT processor's documentation.

You can then use the `$barcode` parameter in an 'attribute value template' in your otherwise-literal markup:

```
<fo:block-container left="1000" top="1000"
        z-index="1" position="relative">
        <fo:block>
            <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                <bc:barcode xmlns:bc="http://barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns"
                    message="{$barcode}">
                    <bc:ean-13 />
                </bc:barcode>
            </fo:instream-foreign-object>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
```

For attribute value templates in XSLT 1.0, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template

Comment: Thanks for the help. So I have added the parameter to the XSLT sheet. However, when I give the parameter a static value "<xsl:param name="messageCode" select="444333222111"/>" it works. But if a remove the static value and set the parameter in java on the XSLT Transformer, the value does not get displayed when the XSLT document is generated. It instead says "java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter msg must not be empty" which refers to the message on barcode4j that is not allowed to be empty.

Comment: Is it 'msg' or 'message'?

To test stylesheet parameters, can you temporarily go back to hardcoding the `@message` value and use the parameter value elsewhere?  E.g., you could put `<xsl:value-of select="$messageCode"/>` in some other template where you can check in the output that the parameter is being set properly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It says "msg" because its referring to an implicit implementation in the Barcode4j lib when the message is not set. 

If you do '<bc:barcode xmlns:bc="barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns"; message=""> <bc:ean-13 /> </bc:barcode>' - then it will give the same NullPointerException error.

Comment: Yes, I have tried using the parameter in other places, as you mentioned and it does in fact print the value that is set in java when the document is generated. When for example I give a static value to the parameter AND set the value in java, for ex - '<xsl:value-of select="$messageCode" select="123123123123"/>' then the barcode generated shows the static value, and the '<xsl:value-of select="$messageCode"/>' shows the java value.

Comment: The repeated `select` attribute in `<xsl:value-of select="$messageCode" select="123123123123"/>` isn't well-formed XML, so you should have got an error message long before you got a barcode.  If you generate the FO as a file, what shows up for `@message`?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say `<xsl:param name="messageCode" select="123123123123"/>` instead. This way the barcode message is set to "123123123123" and the `<xsl:value-of select="messageCode"/>` is set to the different code that is set on the java side.

Comment: I found the issue, there was other libs in the resource folder that referenced the javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory classes which caused a conflict somehow when the XSL document is transformed. Thanks for the help Tony